# How can I make external command use current line as input and append output to end of same line?

Tags: normal-mode, external-command

Using  Vim 8.0

I'm trying to make a table where the first column is the name of a file and the second column the creation date of such file, to which I have access by the exif data.

I would like to achieve this in one line, just to learn how.

Currently, I'm using:

`:!ls`

To get all the filenames I'll be working with. (If I want to filter .pdf files from this, how can I grep them out?)

Then, I would like to run something like this:

`:read !exif -t 0x9003 -m`

(which writes the date in the next line) but having the output append to the same line where the filename is, leaving a space or comma to separate the columns.

Was thinking that maybe I should write the ouput of `!exif -t 0x9003 -m` to a register `@a` and then use `:normal $a<C-R>a` to append it, but, again, failed to figure out how to do that.

Another idea was to use `:execute ':normal A ' . "foo"` ,this almost works, but cannot figure out a way to use the output of `exif` instead of "foo".

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this. Go heavy on the Vim or do what a rational person would do in the real world: lean heavily on the shell and let it do all the work as that's its strength. Though this is Vi/Vim SE I'm going to be contrarian and show the practical solution. ;)

Let's say you use Bash and you want to run `exif` on all PNG files in a certain directory. One way is:

```
for f in ~/images/*.png; do
    printf "%s : %s\n" "$f" "$(exif -t XXX -m "$f")"
done
```

The key to this one is the "process substitution" feature `$(exif -t XXX -m "$f")`. You'll get each PNG file name followed by a `:` and then the `exif` command output for that file.

You can just cram that all on a Vim command line like this:

```
:r !for f in ~/images/*.png; do printf "\%s : \%s\n" "$f" "$(exif "$f")"; done
```

(Note that you have to escape `%` here as otherwise Vim interprets them as special characters.)

Or you can put those shell commands in a script and just do:

```
:r !myscript.sh
```

BTW, if you want to loop over all files in a dir except PDFs then you can use `for f in ~/images/*.!(pdf)` but you'll need to first enable that syntax with `shopt -s extglob`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the bulk of the action is happening on external commands here, using a shell script is probably most appropriate in this particular case.

If you do want to execute this inside Vim, then using the [`system()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) function is a great way to execute an external command and get the result into a string. (You can then use `trim()` to remove the trailing newline. You can also use `shellescape()` to escape filenames to safely pass them as arguments to the external command.)

To modify lines in place, I'd recommend using a `:s` command, in particular using [`\=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) in the replacement part to use the result of a Vimscript expression as the replacement. You can then use [`submatch(0)`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#submatch%28%29) to access the original matched text.

Finally, you can use [`:v`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Avglobal) to exclude the lines which have filenames with the `.pdf` extension.

Putting it all together:

```
:v/\.pdf$/s/.\+/\=submatch(0)."\t".trim(system("exif -t 0x9003 -m ".shellescape(submatch(0))))
```

This will append the EXIF info to the lines with the filenames, using a Tab character as a separator.

Assumes your input was acquired with `:0read !ls` or similar, the buffer has a list of filenames to handle. Empty lines will be skipped by the `.\+` match, so they're ok too.

Answer (score 1):

What about using regular `setline` and `getline` functions?

```
call setline('.', getline('.') .. "NEW ADDITION")
```

Couple it with `systemlist` function:

```
call setline('.', getline('.') .. systemlist('date')[0])
```

You will add output of the system `date` to the current line.

I don't have `exif` so this is for you to check:

```
nnoremap <space>d :call setline('.', getline('.') .. systemlist('exif -t -m ' .. getline('.'))[0])<CR>
```

Press `<space>d` to add output of your `exif` to current line.

Or you can use it with `:g` command for all files in a buffer:

```
:g/^/call setline('.', getline('.') .. systemlist('exif -t -m ' .. getline('.'))[0])
```